# Server Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 1 at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

I am using portal1032_win32.exe file to install the weblogic server in my local. After following basic installation by providing password and choosing the folder names and selected jdk which comes through installation. Also created domain by providing the defalut configurationd and chooses adminserver alone.

I have opened the eclipse IDE  comes through this and started. Added the server by choosing base_domain. I have started the server. here is my problem It is taking more time and finally displaying following message "Server Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 1 at localhost failed to start."

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is simple:

add

-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

after -vmargs string in eclipse.ini

Comment: thank you for your comments. some how that problem is gone now. still will check your solutions.